# MVC 3 _ViewStart, purpose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout

Just trying to figure out the purpose of the _ViewStart page in Razor? The only thing that i manage to do in this file is to specify the layout to use. I can't render content to the layout, just specify it. It addresses the DRY pattern by allowing you to just tell the engine once what layout to use and to avoid having Layout calls on every page. But has it any other purpose then setting the layout?

Answer (score 4):

No other purpose i know of, but keep in mind that you can have a different _viewstart file for each controller, so that each can use a different masterpage..

So by putting a _viewstart file in the `/Views/<controllername>` you can specify a layout for all actions of that controller, that override the global _viewstart.